# Mocking xml file for unit testing with Rhinomocks

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I want to mock xml used as below for unit tests.I am using Rhinomocks framework for mocking.How can I unit test my methods by not using the actual xml file.Do I have to change my code structure.

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyService : IMyService
{       
    private readonly string mSchemaPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data",
        "schema_0.1.xsd");        
    private readonly string mXmlPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data",
        "MyDataRecords.xml");

    private XDocument mXDocument;

    public MyService()
    {
        try
        {
            //load xml document
            mXDocument = XDocument.Load(mXmlPath);               

            if (mXDocument == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Null returned while reading xml file");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           //my exception management code
        }
    }

    public List<MyDataRecords> GetAllRecords()
    {
        ////fetch records from xDocument

       mXDocument.Save();
    }
    public void AddRecord(MyRecord record)
    {
        ////add record

       mXDocument.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyService.UnitTests")]
public class MyService : IMyService
{

private readonly string mSchemaPath;

private readonly string mXmlPath; 


 public MyService()
        : this(
            Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data", "MyDataRecords.xml"),
            Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data", "schema_0.1.xsd"))
    {

    }

internal MyService(string xmlPath,string schemaPath)
{        
    try
    {
         mXmlPath=xmlPath;
         mSchemaPath=schemaPath;

        //load xml document
        mXDocument = Xdocument.Laod(mXmlPath);

        if (mXDocument == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Null returned while reading xml file");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //my exception management code
    }
}

public List<MyRecord> GetAllRecords()
{
    ////fetch records from xDocument

    mXDocument.Save();
}

public void AddRecord(MyRecord record)
{
    ////add record

    mXDocument.Save();
}
```

}

Comment: This is my modified class,this looks simple to me.@Jonathon Do you see any issues here.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

I've modified your MyService class to have an overloaded constructor, which accepts `Func<string, XDocument>` to load an XDocument, and also `Func<string>` to resolve the value that corresponds to `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` . When the default constructor is called, the same call to XDocument.Load is performed, and likewise for using `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath` in building the path to the xml and xsd files.

However in an unit test you could call the other constructor like this:

```
        const string mockDirectory = "TEST";
        var expectedXmlPath = Path.Combine(mockDirectory, "App_Data", "MyDataRecords.xml");
        string xmlPathPassed = "";
        var service = new MyService(path =>
            {
                xmlPathPassed = path;
                return XDocument.Parse("<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>");
            },
            () => mockDirectory);
        Assert.Equal(expectedXmlPath, xmlPathPassed);
```

You could also expose the XDocument on the Service, perhaps through a readonly property and check that the XDocument represents the Mocked xml.

MyService:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
private const string AppDataDirectoryName = "App_Data";
private const string SchemaFileName = "schema_0.1.xsd";
private const string XmlFileName = "MyDataRecords.xml";
private readonly Func<string, XDocument> mdocumentLoader;
private readonly Func<string> mAppDataDirectoryBuilder;
private readonly string mSchemaPath = "";
private readonly string mXmlPath = "";
private XDocument mXDocument;

public MyService() : this(XDocument.Load, () => HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath)
{
}

public MyService(Func<string, XDocument> documentLoader, Func<string> appDataDirectoryBuilder)
{
    mdocumentLoader = documentLoader;
    mAppDataDirectoryBuilder = appDataDirectoryBuilder;
    try
    {
        var baseDirectory = mAppDataDirectoryBuilder();
        mSchemaPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, AppDataDirectoryName, SchemaFileName);
        mXmlPath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, AppDataDirectoryName, XmlFileName);
        mXDocument = mdocumentLoader(mXmlPath);

        if (mXDocument == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Null returned while reading xml file");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //my exception management code
    }
}

public List<MyRecord> GetAllRecords()
{
    ////fetch records from xDocument
    return null;
    //mXDocument.Save();
}

public void AddRecord(MyRecord record)
{
    ////add record
    // mXDocument.Save(record);
}
```

}

Comment: This is brilliant suggestion,without breaking much of code structure I can achieve this.Only concern is other constructor can be used by clients also.How can I block that?

Comment: This method of unit testing has been useful when retrofitting tests into legacy code. I'm yet to discover a way to not expose that extra constructor though. The testability payoff outweighs that design issue in my books.

Comment: On problem here this line 
            mXDocument = _xdocumentLoader(mXmlPath); always load the original xml.

Comment: Does your code read mXDocument = _xdocumentLoader(mXmlPath); I made an edit to update this line. I just tried this and it worked  var service = new MyService(path => XDocument.Parse("<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"));

Comment: Actually mXmlPath is intialized before constructor is called.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly. In the above example mXmlPath is always initialised for both the production and unit testing scenarios, which is fine. In the unit testing scenario, the call `var service = new MyService(irrelevantPath => XDocument.Parse("YOUR XML FOR UNIT TESTING"));`, ignores the 'irrelevantPath' (mXmlPath) and just parses the xml string, no xml file is actually loaded. Does your unit test load the xml string?

Comment: problem is HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath is null in unit test environment.

Comment: I see now, I'll update my code example to show how I'd go about making this service easier to test. It involves more IoC and separation of concerns.

Comment: Why not simply make the Test only constructor internal and then extend your internals so they are accessible to your unit tests? `internal MyService() : this(XDocument.Load, () => HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath)
{}` and then in your AssemblyInfo.cs `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyUnitTestAssembly")]`

Comment: @AlSki That seems like a reasonable solution to hiding the Test only constructor. Which in this case might be a good approach. I typically use this IoC approach in legacy code, as the existing calls to the original constructor remain untouched. However if given a choice from the beginning, in this particular example, the only constructor I would have is the one with the Func<T>'s and I'd let my container resolve it all. It's highly configurable, completed separates the concern of the dependency (no slightly hidden code like this(XDocument.Load...), from the service itself.

Comment: @JonathonLee I think the most abstract differentiation for test constructor should be determined by the very basic need of having a separate constructor for unit test which is path of different XML file.In future if I change to use any other file type ,path should be sufficient for testing purpose and this way Iam free to use any document parser than Xdocument.